# Numpy Array Larger Than Equivalent List

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I am not able to figure out why a saved 10000 X 10000 X 7 sized Numpy array with dtype=np.float16 is 1.4gb, whereas the equivlant pickled Python list is roughly 500mb. I would expect that the Python pickled list would be larger than the Numpy array.

In Python, I have a list called all_games, and each list contains 7 subelement float values.

I then sample from all_games using the following function:

```
def sample_games(all_games, file_name):
    all_games = np.array(all_games, dtype=np.float16)
    DRAW = 10000
    SAMPLE = 10000
    # Generate random indices for the sample
    sampled_indices = rng.choice(all_games.shape[0], size=(SAMPLE, DRAW), replace=True)
    # Get all sub-elements from randomly sampled indices
    sampled_data = all_games[sampled_indices]

    file_name = '***'
    np.save(file_name, sampled_data)
```

This saves a 10000,10000,7 Numpy array that is 1.4gb large.

If I don't convert the list to a Numpy array, and instead use the following function:

```
def sample_games(all_games, file_name):
    DRAW = 10000
    SAMPLE = 10000
    # Generate random indices for the sample
    # Get all sub-elements from randomly sampled indices
    sampled_data = [[random.choice(all_games) for _ in range(DRAW)] for _ in range(SAMPLE)]

    file_name = '***'
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(sampled_data, file)
```

the pickled list is 500mb.

Can someone explain why the saved Numpy array is roughly 900mb larger than the equivalent pickled list, and how I can shrink the saved Numpy array to a size smaller than the equivalent pickled list?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why do you expect the pickled numpy array to be smaller than the python list?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @jared! I am fairly new to Python, but it is my understanding that Numpy array structures are more compact/memory efficient than Python lists, tuples, etc. Is this not correct?

Comment: 10000 X 10000 X 7  x 2 bytes = 1.4Gb.  So the array save makes sense.  It's harder to estimate the memory use of the nested list, and from that the pickle dump size.

Comment: How large is `all_games`?

Comment: For the first array case, what is `len(pickle.dumps(sampled_data.tolist()))`?  This converts the array to nested iist and then to pickle string.

Comment: I appreciate all of the responses. I tried pickling the list using the pickle function above. Then, I unpickled the list and ran print(sys.getsizeof(pickle.dumps(unpickled_data, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))) where unpickled_data is the unpickled list. The result is 504.652465 mb, which is roughly the size of the pickled file on my harddrive. I'm still struggling to understand how Numpy is creating an array 2x the size of a pickled list of the same format.

Answer (score 3):

NumPy doesn't compress, you get the raw 10000×10000×7×16 bits = 1.4 GB. You could try [numpy.savez_compressed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html).

Pickle doesn't compress, either, but you're repeatedly referencing the same inner 7-elements list objects from `all_games`, and pickle doesn't explicitly store them repeatedly. Try `sampled_data = [[random.choice(all_games).copy() for _ in range(DRAW)] for _ in range(SAMPLE)]` (I just added `.copy()`) to see what happens when it can't take advantage of that and you'll likely end up with 4.4 GB.